# Samsung Captivate AT&T OTA Update Stuck at 99%

Tags: stock-android, att, ota-update, samsung-captivate

I have a Samsung Captivate (Galaxy S). I recently returned to stock firmware (2.1) using ODIN 1-click and have been trying to do the standard update to 2.2 from AT&T.

The download goes pretty quickly until it reaches 99%. At that point it is just stuck (I've waited about 20 minutes so far). I have tried to hit cancel and then resume. This just restarts my phone, goes to a white screen with an update bar, and hits 50% before the update fails and it boots normally.

What could be wrong and how can I get the standard OTA update to work?

Comment: If it helps, I am on wifi and I can see that my connection works in a browser on the phone. I didn't want to kill my data usage so I wanted to stick with wifi.

Comment: Why don't you Odin to 2.2?

Comment: I'm trying to remove traces of any "custom software" so that my warranty is still valid. Headphone jack is busted.

Answer (score 1):

I found this: http://ars.samsung.com/customer/usa/jsp/faqs/faqs_view_us.jsp?SITE_ID=22&PG_ID=2&PROD_SUB_ID=557&PROD_ID=558&AT_ID=368733 and it seems to be working. I'm not really sure now what that OTA update was but I'll ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Odin-ing to 2.2 should be no different than Odin-ing to 2.1.  If you flash pure stock no traces will be left in the system or data partitions of any rooting or custom ROMs or whatever.  You may need to clean your internal/external SD to remove folders from apps that require root, just in case, but that's about it.

[This XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1300843) has 1-click Odin for 2.2.  The non-rooted version is supposed to still be odexed, according to one of the messages in the thread, and thus should be pure stock.

That said: Why do you need 2.2 to return for a warranty?  They shouldn't care whether or not you updated as long as your 2.1 is also official.

Comment: I mostly just assumed that the ODIN version may have slight differences (like going into phone status and looking at the version, etc.) so I figured going from that to the "official" one would be completely clean.

Comment: @Matt OTAs generally only work from a specific version, so if the version you Odined too was bad then you wouldn't be able to use the OTA anyways.